# How to remove namespaces from XML and add new namespaces?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am receiving XML file with proper data. the receiver of the XML does not want few XML namespaces that I do not know why.

And few new namespaces should be added.

I have input file as

```
<Document xmlns="http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01 http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01/e-commerce_101.xsd"
          System="HighJump"
          Version="101">
   <Header>
      <SenderEndpointID qualifier="EAN">98989898</SenderEndpointID>
      <ReceiverEndpointID qualifier="EAN">98989898</ReceiverEndpointID>
      <CreatedDate>13-06-2017</CreatedDate>
      <CreatedTime>10:18:00</CreatedTime>
      <EDIRefNo>6136</EDIRefNo>
      <Test>false</Test>
      <AcknowledgementRequest>No</AcknowledgementRequest>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <DispatchReference>6136</DispatchReference>
      <DocumentType>ORDERS</DocumentType>
      <DocumentNo>98989898</DocumentNo>
      <DocumentDate>13-06-2017</DocumentDate>
      <RequestedDeliveryDate>19-06-2017</RequestedDeliveryDate>
      <CurrencyCode>DKK</CurrencyCode>
      <ExternalDocumentNo>100718360</ExternalDocumentNo>
      <ShipmentMethodCode>DAP</ShipmentMethodCode>
      <Parties>
         <Party type="Sellto">
            <No>98989898</No>
         </Party>
         <Party type="StoreNumber">
            <No>98989898</No>
         </Party>
         <Party type="Supplier">
            <No>98989898</No>
         </Party>
      </Parties>
      <Lines>
         <Line>
            <LineNo>1</LineNo>
            <DocumentNo>100718360</DocumentNo>
            <EANNo>98989898</EANNo>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            <UnitofMeasure>PCE</UnitofMeasure>
            <UnitPrice>166.91</UnitPrice>
         </Line>
         <Line>
            <LineNo>2</LineNo>
            <DocumentNo>100718360</DocumentNo>
            <EANNo>98989898</EANNo>
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
            <UnitofMeasure>PCE</UnitofMeasure>
            <UnitPrice>166.91</UnitPrice>
         </Line>
      </Lines>
   </Body>
</Document>
```

I need to remove few namespaces and add some new namespaces. 
Output should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  SystemVersion="7.00.3.71.03"  System="HighJump"  Version="101">
  <Header>
    <SenderEndpointID qualifier="EAN">98989898</SenderEndpointID>
    <ReceiverEndpointID qualifier="EAN">98989898</ReceiverEndpointID>
    <CreatedDate>13-06-2017</CreatedDate>
    <CreatedTime>10:18:00</CreatedTime>
    <EDIRefNo>6136</EDIRefNo>
    <Test>false</Test>
    <AcknowledgementRequest>No</AcknowledgementRequest>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <DispatchReference>6136</DispatchReference>
    <DocumentType>ORDERS</DocumentType>
    <DocumentNo>98989898</DocumentNo>
    <DocumentDate>13-06-2017</DocumentDate>
    <RequestedDeliveryDate>19-06-2017</RequestedDeliveryDate>
    <CurrencyCode>DKK</CurrencyCode>
    <ExternalDocumentNo>100718360</ExternalDocumentNo>
    <ShipmentMethodCode>DAP</ShipmentMethodCode>
    <Parties>
      <Party type="Sellto">
        <No>98989898</No>
      </Party>
      <Party type="StoreNumber">
        <No>98989898</No>
      </Party>
      <Party type="Supplier">
        <No>98989898</No>
      </Party>
    </Parties>
    <Lines>
      <Line>
        <LineNo>1</LineNo>
        <DocumentNo>100718360</DocumentNo>
        <EANNo>98989898</EANNo>
        <Quantity>5</Quantity>
        <UnitofMeasure>PCE</UnitofMeasure>
        <UnitPrice>166.91</UnitPrice>
      </Line>
      <Line>
        <LineNo>2</LineNo>
        <DocumentNo>100718360</DocumentNo>
        <EANNo>98989898</EANNo>
        <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        <UnitofMeasure>PCE</UnitofMeasure>
        <UnitPrice>166.91</UnitPrice>
      </Line>
    </Lines>
  </Body>
</Document>
```

I was trying with XSLT script to remove first and then add. But it's not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl    = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi    = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd    = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!--Identity template,  provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to remove following namespaces

```
xmlns="http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01 http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01/e-commerce_101.xsd"
```

And add following namesapces

```
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
SystemVersion="7.00.3.71.03"
```

Comment: 1. What do you need an unused namespace declaration for? 2. `SystemVersion="7.00.3.71.03"` is an attribute, not a namespace.

Comment: how to add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove a namespace, what you are actually doing is creating new elements with the same local names, but not in any namespace. This template would do this:

```
<xsl:template match="*" priority="-0.4">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The priority is to give it higher priority than the identity template (which has priority -0.5).

To `xsi:schemaLocation`, which is an attribute in a namespace, you can just have a simple template to ignore it

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation" />
```

And to add the unnecessary namespace declaration for xsd, you would need to match the root element `Document` and add it there. You can also add the `SystemVersion` attribute at the same time.

```
<xsl:template match="/e:Document">
    <Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SystemVersion="7.00.3.71.03">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of a namespace prefix here, to ensure it matches a `Document` element that is in the namespace specified in the XML (The prefix `e` will be bound to the same namespace in the XSLT).

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl    = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:e      = "http://rep.evenex.dk/schema/evenex/eBusiness_01"
    xmlns:xsi    = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    exclude-result-prefixes="e xsi">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!--Identity template,  provides default behavior that copies all content into the output -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" priority="-0.4">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="/e:Document">
      <Document xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" SystemVersion="7.00.3.71.03">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </Document>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```